# A variable from useState within a hook callback is closured

Tags: react-hooks

I use [useKey](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useKey.md) to respond to Enter.

```
const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

useKey("Enter", ev => {
     console.log("ev, isFocused -> ", ev, isFocused);
});
```

However, the isFocused value printed is always false even if it was changed.

How can one prevent a useState variable from being frozen to the initial value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`useKey` hook](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useKey.ts#L24) supports dependencies (4th param):

```
const useKey = (key: KeyFilter, fn: Handler = noop, opts: UseKeyOptions = {}, deps: DependencyList = [key])
```

Wrap the event handler with `useCallback` and set it's dependancy to be `isFocused`, and then pass the event handler as a dependancy to `useKey`. If `isFocused` changes, `eventHandler` changes, and `useKey` will update accordingly:

```
const eventHandler = useCallback(ev => {
  console.log("ev, isFocused -> ", ev, isFocused);
}, [isFocused])

useKey("Enter", eventHandler, {}, [eventHandler]);
```